# PostGIS Query using ST_Intersects not using spatial index

Tags: postgis, st-intersects, st-geometry

As code is better than 1000 words, here we go :

```
explain analyze SELECT DISTINCT(zones.office_id) AS office_id FROM "zones" JOIN offices ON zones.office_id = offices.id WHERE ST_Intersects('SRID=4326;POINT (46.596759 24.83072)', geom_polygon);

                                                                  QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=1000.28..132224.81 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=88.062..3704.773 rows=142 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1000.28..132224.81 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=88.041..3702.915 rows=142 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (zones.office_id = office.id)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 280876
         ->  Index Only Scan using offices_pkey on offices  (cost=0.28..81.96 rows=1979 width=8) (actual time=0.067..13.083 rows=1979 loops=1)
               Heap Fetches: 0
         ->  Materialize  (cost=1000.00..132113.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.943 rows=142 loops=1979)
               ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..132113.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6.076..67.874 rows=142 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 1
                     Workers Launched: 1
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on zones  (cost=0.00..131113.06 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.867..7.143 rows=71 loops=2)
                           Filter: st_intersects('0101000020E6100000FD4B5299624C47401422E010AAD43840'::geometry, geom_polygon)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 4309
 Planning Time: 0.313 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 13
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 1.674 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.374 ms, Emission 5.101 ms, Total 7.149 ms
 Execution Time: 3707.258 ms
(19 rows)
```

Why is my simple query leading to a sequential scan instead of index scan?

Of course I have a gist index on the area column.

Comment: probably because you only have 71 rows and it isn't worth loading the index

Comment: It's 142 rows (`rows=71 loops=2`) that get returned. But the actual decision *should* have been the fact that the *Index Only Scan* on `offices` returned 1979 matching rows - which is still too few to load the index. You can try to coerce the planner by adding `'SRID=4326;POINT (46.596759 24.83072)' && geom_polygon AND ST_Intersects(...)`.

Comment: But still the query is slow, 120ms...

Comment: Looks like it's 30 times faster than the above? Point-in-Polygon algorithms are not for free, and they linearly decrease in performance with increasing vertex count. Depending on your areas, this may have a significant impact. You may want to `ST_SubDivide` those *Polygon*s to increase index efficiency.

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the geoms in the st_intersects? Ex. ST_Intersects(geom_poly, geom_pt)

Comment: I tried to switch @BrentEdwards but it changed nothing.

Comment: Can you add the command you used to create your index ? Also make sure to run an `ANALYZE` on your table